# How to send a payload of char arrays via struct.pack?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

I'm trying to send a message via udp from a python script to a c++ client application.  The app uses two structs and I cannot change these.

```cpp
struct myType{
  double              var1;
  double              var2;
};

struct message {
  char                payload[40];
  short               id;
  unsigned char       msg_state;
};
```

On the python side I have a script that does basically this

```python
var1 = float(input())
var2 = float(input())
id = 1
msg_state = 0
payload1 = struct.pack("dd", var1, var2)
payload2 = struct.pack("<40shB", payload1, id, msg_state)
# socket code here
```

This successfully sends a udp message but I've noticed that the contents of the payload do not line up with my input and the captured value changes every time.  I've also tried the code snippet below (with payload preappended by an additional 40 0s as well) but it also does not work in the same manner.

```python
payload1="000000009a999999999901409a99999999990140"
id = 1
msg_state = 0
s = bytes(payload, 'utf-8')
payload2 = struct.pack("<40shB", s, id, msg_state)
# socket code here
```

I would like to know if there is there is a problem in the python script I have.  I have no idea why every time I run this script and try to access var1 in the payload it keeps changing.  Am I not using the `struct` module correctly?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and provide a runnable [mre] illustrating the problem? i.e. Something that round-trips all the values.

Comment: I can provide a minimal reproducible example for the python script but unfortunately not so for the c++ side due to the nature of the work.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is it might be an alignment issue. C++ compilers sometimes (via compile-time options) by "padding" thing to make the fields in structures alight with word boundaries. The `struct` module [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) mentions this and describes how to deal with it (via format characters). This might be visible by noting _how_ the payload isn't lining-up—is there a pattern?

Comment: can't say theres any recognizable patterns.  When I put in 2.2 and 2.2 for both inputs I get    `'\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\x01@\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\x01@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x04`

Comment: ^for the packed message.  The extra 3 hex numbers at the end are not a mistake my actual message struct has more variables.  As for extracting the payload from the c++ im getting random variations usually in with var1 being in the millions range even though I only put in 2.2

Comment: The size of the `Struct` for `payload1` — obtained with `print(struct.Struct("dd").size)` — is 16, so I'm not sure where you're getting  the `40s` being used in the `payload2` struct format.